# SystemCommands.[SomeWindowAction] outside of commands:

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5

Why does calling SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this) outside of a handler for a command binding that binds to the related system command not work?

Why do these SystemCommands methods even exist? It seems like all of that functionality could be done through the window itself.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

SystemCommands' static methods were introduced in .NET 4.5 as preferred way to common window operations.
Under the hood they are implemented using non-blocking [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) function as opposed to blocking [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950) (window.Close()) or [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx) functions (window.WindowState).

They should work just fine even outside the command binding handler (provided the window is shown):

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="close" Name="CloseButton" Click="CloseButton_Click" />
        <Button Content="maximize" Name="MaximizeButton" Click="MaximizeButton_Click" />
        <Button Content="restore" Name="RestoreButton" Click="RestoreButton_Click" />
        <Button Content="minimize" Name="MinimizeButton" Click="MinimizeButton_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
        }
        private void MaximizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this);
        }
        private void RestoreButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(this);
        }
        private void MinimizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
        }
    }
```

---

*Original answer:*

First off, [commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) are very useful design pattern to decouple the source from the target of method call by encapsulating it in an object.

You close a window (target) by calling its `Close()` method but often this action is triggered by user e.g. clicking on a button (source). If your UI is extremely simple it might be an overkill to encapsulate this action in a command (`button.Click` handler calls `window.Close()`) but [typically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) it's desirable to not tie UI elements to each other directly (`button.Click` handler executes `command` which calls `window.Close()`).

[SystemCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcommands.aspx), [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx), [ComponentCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.componentcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [MediaCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mediacommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [NavigationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.navigationcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [EditingCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are just implementations of ICommand interface (following the command pattern) so you don't have to worry about creating these typical objects yourself.

The actual wiring of these commands to targets and sources is up to you (that's why just executing them won't do anything).

Finally, since all these commands are [RoutedCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a more suitable approach in tune with MVVM is to avoid them and implement your own [RelayCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) ([DelegateCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx)) that are part of your ViewModel.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. I'm asking how/why the static methods in the SystemCommands class that are typically linked up via command bindings to be invoked by the static SystemCommand ICommand instances do not work identically outside of this usage. Why can't I arbitrarily call SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this) anywhere in my window code? And the functionality of those static methods can all be handled through the window itself, so why even have the static methods? I am not asking why the commands exist, nor am I asking how to use commands.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "outside of command binding usage"? In my example I invoke the static methods without any command binding. 
Unless you call them within constructor they work (and as opposed to e.g. window.Close(), do not block the current thread).